# Setting exit code from an Ansible callback plugin

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am writing an Ansible 2.x callback plugin, and I would like to be able to fail the current playbook with an non-zero exit code based on some conditions in the `v2_playbook_on_stats` function.

I have tried to `raise AnsibleError()`, but this is caught somewhere up the chain and treated as a warning, which allows Ansible to finish with a zero exit code.

I have also tried using `self._display.error()`, but seems to do nothing but display an error message, and again Ansible finishes with a zero exit code.

Is there any way to do what I require?  Or is a callback plugin never meant to allow the developer to change the status of a playbook to a failure?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with callback, strategy plugin is your choice.

Subclass required plugin (e.g. `linear`), extend [run](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/9233ece2245f98c8101b866fcd840c9b4db446b3/lib/ansible/plugins/strategy/linear.py#L170) method to return non-zero value based on your criteria, it will be translated by PlaybookExecutor and cli as program exit code.

Answer (score 1):

Also faced the same problem and i found out that i could use python's `sys.exit(x)` (x being the various exit codes) to stop or fail the playbook.